# "Resource not valid: must be an absolute path with no references to parent directories" error when iterating through a folder

Tags: file-io, rust

I'm new to Rust and the ggez game engine, and I am trying to load in a bunch of images from one folder. I keep getting the same error.

I've tried using the `Path` type, `String`s, full directory to the file, and string literals and nothing seems to work. I've spent about 6 hours of coding on this issue.

This is the code that seems to be the problem:

```
for number in 0..read_dir("resources/images")?.count() - 1 {
    let image_path = format!("{0}/{1}.png", "resources/images", number);
    images.push(graphics::Image::new(ctx, image_path)?);
}
```

I expect all the files to load in. It's that simple.
[Here's a git repository of a MCVE](https://github.com/15024/opening_files/tree/9a74c6155be8a0783d23a29c71aa8a4e9b2541d8).

I've also tried using the `DirEntry` type:

```
for (number, item) in fs::read_dir(&images_path)?.enumerate() {
    images.push(graphics::Image::new(ctx, item?.path())?);
}
```

It yields the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an iterator over a range, rather than the iterator provided by `read_dir()?`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an absolute path as the error message says?

Comment: Sorry, was busy over the weekend, I did try to use `read_dir()?`, but that led to the same error message. Using the absolute path (from C:/ to resources/images) didn't work either, same error message.

Comment: @DavidMartin Can you include the code you used for an absolute path? My understanding of the ggez filesystem is that the code wants an absolute path from the virtual root, like `/images`.

Comment: I assumed that by absolute path I would just replace `resources/images` with `C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/MyRustFolder/project_name/resources/images`

Comment: Do `/resources/images` or `/images` work for you as absolute paths? `ggez` abstracts away the filesystem, so you shouldn't have to use an absolute path with any details about your local system.

Comment: I've tried `/resources/images`.
Not `/images`. If I remember correctly it says it cannot find the directory.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MCVE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: While links are great as *additional* context, they are no substitute for the MCVE being present directly *in the question*